# Find name of offending cop in Rubocop output

Tags: ruby, rubocop

After running Rubocop:

```
bundle exec rubocop
```

I get this output:

```
Inspecting 3 files
C..

Offenses:

lib/main.rb:145:3: C: Use SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE for constants.
  InternalCache = if RUBY_ENGINE == 'ruby'
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

3 files inspected, 1 offense detected
```

My question is: how can I find the name of the rule I have to disable, if I choose to ignore this offense.

The name I'm looking for is the name I'd use in a `# rubocop:disable` comment:

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/BlockLength
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `rubocop -h` you'll see there's an option `--display-cop-names`.

(it seems this is [enabled by default](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/pull/5037) so maybe you're on an old version of RuboCop).

Comment: ...Or as shown on that link, maybe you have explicitly set `DisplayCopNames` to `false` in your configuration.

Comment: It was an old version of Rubocop (0.49.1 in my case). Thank you very much!