# Rubocop: RuboCop found unknown Ruby version 3.1 in `.ruby-version`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I recently upgraded ruby version from 2.7.5 to 3.1.1 and when I try to run `rubocop` I get error `Error: RuboCop found unknown Ruby version 3.1 in` .ruby-version`. Supported versions: 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7`
Looking at the rubocop [compatibility](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/compatibility.html) documentation it supports 3.1 version. Any idea why I am getting the error?

.rubocop.yml:

```
require: rubocop-rspec
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'bin/*'
    - 'vendor/**/*'
Metrics/BlockLength:
  Exclude:
    - 'spec/**/*'
Metrics/LineLength:
  Exclude:
    - 'spec/**/*'
RSpec/AnyInstance:
  Enabled: false
RSpec/ExampleLength:
  Exclude:
    - 'spec/**/*'
Style/BracesAroundHashParameters:
  Enabled: false
```

Comment: Did you try updating `rubocop`? `bundle update rubocop` or something similar

Comment: It could be that the individual cop isn't that compatible, what version of Rubocop are you using? Does the stack trace contain the name of the cop?

Comment: @Deepesh I did try that but no luck. In my gemfile rubocop is set as `gem 'rubocop', '0.77.0', require: false`

Comment: @max I am using `0.77.0` version of rubocop. How can I get stack trace? I just get the error when I run rubocop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64145879/find-name-of-offending-cop-in-rubocop-output

Comment: 0.77.0 is very old (Nov 2019). Try setting `gem "rubocop", "~> 1.26.1"` and run `bundle` - it should indicate what's preventing the update.

Comment: @AndyWaite Tried that and after running rubocop got this error
`Error: The `Style/BracesAroundHashParameters` cop has been removed. Please use  and/or  instead.
(obsolete configuration found in .rubocop.yml, please update it)`

Comment: That is what Max said in the second comment, you would have to remove/update the obsolete configuration from `rubocop.yml`, the cop you are getting error for has been removed due to: https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/issues/7641 once done then you can update your gem and the ruby version should be supported.

Comment: OP - Curious. Did you resolve this?  (Most of the commenters did not seem to have read the original post.)

Comment: OP - None of the comments were helpful.  Weirdly, 'gem install rubocop' fixed the problem. Why Gemfile was not pulling the most recent gem, I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

Rubocop version `0.77.0` doesn't support newest ruby versions. Make sure to use newer rubocop:

```
gem install rubocop -v 1.14.0
```

You can check what ruby versions are supported by which rubocop version in `lib/rubocop/target_ruby.rb` file, `KNOWN_RUBIES` const.

E. g. supported ruby versions for rubocop version 1.14.0: https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/v1.14.0/lib/rubocop/target_ruby.rb#L7